# Opening a form, closing it, then opening it again in the same location

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a pop up selector for my main form that comes up when I click a button. After I make my selection the box is closed and I continue my work in the main form. However if I go to click that button again, the pop up will appear slightly under where it had opened up previously. Is there a way to fix this so that every time that form is opened it opens in the same spot?

Comment: This is winforms, right? You'll get more attention if you tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: StartPosition = Manual, then use a Point variable to set the Location property of the form to the previous position.

Comment: thanks for edits and answers guys, got what I needed

Comment: @CapnJack you might want to consider a check if the user uses more then one screen to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `StartPosition` on the `Form` to `Manual`

[image]

...then give it a fixed value for `Location`:

[image]

If you need it to be in a fixed location *relative to the parent* (other than `CenterParent`), you'll need to calculate that every time you show it, and set `Location` accordingly.

Comment: perfect thanks so much! Is there an easy way to center this? Or am I gunna have to pull out the calculator lol

Comment: @CapnJack Look at the options on that dropdown in the first image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the applications should open every time at the same location irrespective of the point from where it was closed, then simply set the `Start Position` to `Manual` and set it's `location`.

But if you want that it should open at the point from where it was closed, then you need to set the `Start Position` to `Manual` and save the location on closing of form in `Settings.Settings` file.